# GCF and LCM of high-order polynomials by synthetic division

Tags: polynomials

I have heard from a friend that through synthetic division finding GCF and LCM are quite easy to find for large polynomials where it's difficult to factorise. Does anyone know the method to do this because I cannot find any mention of it on the web?

Comment: This is what you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor

Comment: You don’t want synthetic division (which can only determine  degree one factors), you want long division. It’s exactly the same way that you can find gcds and lcms of integers using long division rather than factorization.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin there are methods to do this with the synthetic division. I know it because in the book "A synopsis of Elementary Results in Pure and Applied Mathematics" https://www.amazon.co.uk/Synopsis-Elementary-Results-Applied-Mathematics/dp/1108050670 The author clearly states that the question is possible and can be done thorough synthetic division

Comment: Euclidean algorithm

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank You some much I think this might be the solution

Comment: see the link that was provided above by @EthanBolker

Comment: @gouthamyalamanchili: It is possible that what you are calling "synthetic division" is not what I call synthetic division; what I understand as synthetic division only allows you to discover linear factors of a polynomial, and as such would be the wrong tool to use for this problem, period.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin i suggest you have a look at the book "a synopsis of elementary results" in the first chapter there is a method to do this but its very difficult to understand but is very efficient than normal methods

Comment: @gouthamyalamanchili: That is a useless bibliographic reference if I ever saw one.